Electric field from dipoles
I study from YouTube. The teacher there gave a question (1):

And he used the formula $$2E=r\frac{dB}{dt}$$(2) and simply integrated using $dV=-Ed\ell$ along that path in electrostatic conditions.
But my question is, when he had derived this formula (2) he used the symmetry and argued that as the magnetic field region is circular so we can…
$$
\begin{align}
\varepsilon
 &= \pi r^2 \frac d{dt}B(t) \\
 &= \frac{\text{work done}}q \\
 &= \frac1q \oint q\vec E_\text{ind}\cdot d\vec\ell \\
 &= \oint \vec E_\text{ind}\cdot d\vec\ell \\
 &= \oint E_\text{ind} d\ell \cos 0 \\
 &= E_\text{ind} 2\pi r
\end{align}
$$
But then my question is, this time, in electrostatic conditions as because of induced charges there is not a complete symmetry as there is a charge separation then how can we use that formula (2) in question (1)?
Another thing I wanted to ask, that in the derivation of (2) in the circular region he used $\varepsilon=\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ but there is no actual loop there, so is it correct to do that?
I added the term dipole in the question because the charge separation created which changes our answer I think there are going to form dipoles.
Edit:What's wrong with this question neither it's being closed nor being up or down voted neither any comments?

Could you please add some information about the setup? Is it a conducting rod along a chord of a circular homogenous but time dependent magnetic field? What is to be calculated? It will help understanding the question and the calculations.

See the top part of the first image it asks to find the potential difference across the rod

@AnshuGupta It's still not clear what the set up is. If there is a changing B field, then $E = -\nabla \phi - dA/dt$ and "voltage difference $\Delta\phi$" isn't the whole story.

Script can be difficult to read. The style also differs between countries and people. Also, "find $V_B-V_A$" doesn't say anything about the setup. And the image is not that clear. So please give the complete question including the setup.

Actually the teacher had given this much only ,in the video he had said that there is a cylindrical region with a uniformly increasing magnetic field governed by the equation $B=B_ot$ where t is time and the magnetic feild points inside and a conducting rod is placed as shown in the figure  find the potential difference across the rod

This wasn't clear in the question: "there is a cylindrical region with a uniformly increasing magnetic field".

Perhaps you could also add a link to the video?

https://youtu.be/Xca6r2s2Q_A?si=FS2sxNw4XT1PAm4Q.The very first question in this video

"in the derivation of (2) in the circular region he used $\varepsilon=\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ but there is no actual loop there, so is it correct to do that?"
That formula doesn't require a loop of conducting material; it's valid for any positively oriented closed non-selfintersecting curve.

Thankyou please help me with the first question too

What's wrong with this question neither it's being closed nor being up or down voted neither any comments?

The changing magnetic field induces an electric field in the rod. This electric field will make charges reorganize in the rod until a static state is reached where there is no electric field in the rod. But there will be a potential difference; if a cable is connected between the ends of the rod, charges will start to flow and produce a current.
